# Please translate some North related words

Tags: north-korean

I cannot find in vocabularies meanings of some words. Can you please translate them?

그이 (also 그이께서, 그이께서는, I guess it's the same as 그, but maybe in different accent)

수령복 (or 장군복)

대를 이어 (대 has many different meanings, I cannot figure out which of them is mentioned)

또 한분의

Answer (score 3, accepted):

그이 is meaning  “that person”
and 장군복? is (army) general's uniform

대를이어 : by generation

또 한분의: Another person or another one

Comment: Any thoughts on the remaining two phrases? This will make your answer stronger.

Comment: I think, 수령복 or 장군복 means something like 수령/장군 + 행복, because it's clear that 복 is not used for clothes. For example, 대를 이어 수령복을 누리는 조선 does not mean "Korea, which enjoys Leader's clothes generation by generation".
So, does "또 한분의 위대한 선군태양" just mean "another great Songun sun"?

Comment: @HaykAbelyan AFAIK, 복 is a Sino-Korean word derived from Chinese character 福, which means fortune or blessing. It is commonly used in forms like '복이 있다', which means you have been blessed.